# Numpy filtering array by True/False

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2-dim numpy  array  where I want to delete lines where in a scond array is a a "False":

Input:

```
a = np.array[[0, 0, 1]
             [5, 2, 7]
             [3, 12, 0]]

b = np.array[True, False, True]
```

Result:

```
c = np.array[[0, 0, 1]
             [3, 12, 0]]
```

I have searched  a lot  and didn't find a way so far.

Many  thanks  for some hints

Tom

Comment: ok thanks .. didn't found that ..